# hyper parameter of loocv - performance reduce

Tags: hyperparameters, catboost, loocv

I Try to hyper parameter tuning over my model , I have small dataset thus the basic model is evaluatred by LOOCV. for better performance I want to hyper parameter tune the model thus I did the next step:

1. I Run LOOCV
   1.1 for each fold of the LOOCV I run random grid search of multiple parameter
   1.2 I choose the best model of each fold
   1.3 I train the model of the whole fold according the chosen hyper parameters and the test with the single sample that considered a test

Finally when I get the score, the AUC dramatically reduce (by 0.10) I Wonder why  did that happen ?

```
def fit_loocv(self):
    for train_ind, test_ind in self.leave_one_out.split(self.X, self.y):
        X_train, X_test = self.X.iloc[train_ind], self.X.iloc[test_ind]
        y_train, y_test = self.y.iloc[train_ind], self.y.iloc[test_ind]
        # model fit and evaluation
        self.cv_tuning(X_train,y_train,test_ind)
        self.model.fit(X_train, y_train) 
        self.y_pred.append(self.model.predict(X_test))

def cv_tuning(self,X_train,y_train,test_ind):
    params = {
      'depth':[5,6,7],
      'iterations':[250,275,300,325,350,400],
      'learning_rate':[0.05,0.1,0.15],
      'l2_leaf_reg':[0.1],
      'scale_pos_weight' : [len(y_train[y_train==0])/len(y_train[y_train==1])],
      'eval_metric':['AUC'],
      'verbose':[False]
      }
    model = CatBoostClassifier(verbose=False)
    est = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = model,scoring='roc_auc', param_distributions = params, cv = 30,verbose=False,n_iter=20)
    est.fit(X_train,y_train)
    self.model=est.best_estimator_
    return
```